# Content Is cutting

Tags: html, css, angular, .net-core

When i render the html by ngfor loop:

```
<td style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
       <div class="skills-subhead">
           <h3><div *ngFor="let answers of question.answersList"><b style="color: #11A04A;">
             {{ answers.role }}</b> : {{ answers.answer }}</div>
           </h3>
       </div>
</td>
```

the dynamic content is cut off please see in an image:
https://ibb.co/RQPM0hs

Comment: Attach the part of the html that shows the content cut.

Comment: Is there a fixed height on the container?

Comment: It seems like this is HTML/CSS issue not Angular

Comment: I appy that style but still content is cut off: style="width: 100%; margin: 0 5%; padding: 0;  float: none;position: static; overflow: visible; "

Comment: can u see in pic @ Derek that show the content is cut

Comment: see cutting the contect in page see: https://ibb.co/m9Z5r0j please

Comment: try removing your <h3> tag, and have only the ngrof div.

Comment: I remove still not effecting: @ForestG please see ibb.co/m9Z5r0j

Comment: It the content cut vertically? `<td style="width: 100%; height: 100%!important; margin: 0 auto; ">` fixes it?